# AWS WorkDocs API to lock /unlock a document

Tags: amazon-web-services

Does AWSWorkDocs provide API to Lock or unlock a file? I could not find a reference to existing APIs that will allow locking or unlocking of work docs documents

Answer (score 0):

As of now, I think only web client and mobile app support this.

From [Amazon WorkDocs now supports file lock and unlock when you’re editing content](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/05/amazon-workdocs-now-supports-file-lock-and-unlock/#:%7E:text=To%20lock%20a%20file%2C%20start,or%20sync%20changes%20to%20WorkDocs):

> To lock a file, start by accessing it using the WorkDocs web client or mobile app and select Lock from the drop-down menu. A lock icon will appear next to the file name to indicate that the file has been locked.